# Able to install Ubuntu 16.04 but not 18.04 on brand new laptop

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation, live-usb

I'm trying to install the install Ubuntu 18.04.2 on a brand new laptop that came preinstalled with Windows. After reaching [the booting menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvCyM.png), no matter what I select, I get [the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpldp.png) (repeatedly):

```
[some_decimal] ACPI Error: No handler or method for GPE [some_integer], disabling event (20180531/evgpe-835)
```

**I have successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04.6**

Is this more likely to be a hardware or Ubuntu-related software issue?

If it is hardware issue, is there a safe fix?

If it is a software issue, what information should I include when reporting the bug?

---

**Information on laptop**:

Brand: LG Gram 14in (2019 Japanese version)

Processor: intel core i7 8th Gen

Drive: 1Tb NVMe SSD (Western Digital)

Video card (obtained running `sudo lshw -C video` in Ubuntu 16.04

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: iomemory:400-3ff irq:147 memory:4022000000-4022ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Have you tried using the "alternate" text based installer?

Comment: @Gerowen I'm not sure what that is, would you mind providing a link?

Comment: does the live usb/dvd boot to a desktop?  if so what happens when you try to install?

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Many have needed UEFI updates & SSD firmware updates. And if nVidia chip, you need nomodeset boot parameter or other boot parameters. Often issues are common across multiple models of same brand.

Comment: Apparently the "alternative" text based installer is only available for Server Edition, best I can tell.  However, there is a "minimal" network installer for the desktop edition as well.  Those downloads can be found here:

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Comment: Maybe this: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1620772#p1620772

Comment: @kc1di can you see the images in the links? I'm not sure why they don't display in the text.

Comment: @oldfred thanks for your comment, just added specs in the question

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia so that would suggested it is a bug?

Comment: @oldfred if needed, how would I perform those updates? Would you be able to provide a link?

Comment: Not sure it's a bug, the some error message can have multiple causes. But it's worth trying the additional boot parameter.

Comment: UEFI updates are from the vendor. Most systems have a way from within Windows, only a few now support UEFI updates from Linux. Many also can do it directly from UEFI and read the downloaded update file from a FAT32 formated partition either on drive or a flash drive. Same with SSD, you may have to download driver update software and use it. Check with vendor. My search only shows USA site for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a fix but a work  around. Since I was able to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I just upgraded from there following instructions in [this article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-linux-16-04-to-18-04/) .